# Replace elements in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is a clean way to replace elements in an array in ES2019?

This is my code, but it iterates the array multiple times:

```
function findReplace(item, target, replacement){
  return item === target ? replacement : item
}

const a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1]
console.log(a.map(item => findReplace(item, 1, 10))
             .map(item => findReplace(item, 2, 20)))
//[10,20,3,4,5,5,4,3,20,10]
```

Comment: i dont realize that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a map for the translation:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1]
const map = new Map([[1, 10], [2, 20]]); 

console.log(a.map(item => map.get(item)??item))
//[10,20,3,4,5,5,4,3,20,10]
```

If you want to replace values with `null` or even `undefined`, then the `??` operator is not the right tool. In that case:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1]
const map = new Map([[1, null], [2, undefined], [3, 33]]); 

console.log(a.map(item => map.has(item) ? map.get(item) : item))
```

Comment: While I admit `??` is sexy, someone might want to use this to replace say `1` with `null` for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Added a variant in case that should be supported.

Comment: @trincot thank you. I accept your answer. however, I have typo. i look for the clean way to replace element in array es2019 not es6

Comment: My answer actually includes es2020 syntax (the `??` operator). Which part of the es2019 novelties do you think relates to your question? I don't see any. Anyway, you should then also update the tags of your question, so it includes `ecmascript-2019`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `object` called `mapping`.

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1]
const mapping = {1: 10, 2: 20};

const result = a.map(v => mapping[v] || v);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Pls kindly give me your feedback, Many thanks @jacobcan118 ^^!